# PyArrow - Working with larger than memory Arrow IPC (feather) files?

Tags: pyarrow, apache-arrow, feather

I'm trying to work Arrow IPC (feather) files which are larger than memory. [PyArrow's documentation notes that "Arrow IPC files can be memory-mapped locally, which allow you to work with data bigger than memory"](https://arrow.apache.org/use_cases/). However, using the default memory map still overflows the memory. This makes sense, as the default is presumably attempting to still allocate the full memory size for the file. So my next thought would be to specify a memory map size smaller than the file similar to what can be done with Python's built-in mmap length. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any way to specify a smaller memory map for the PyArrow memory map. Something like [`pyarrow.feather.read_feather`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.feather.read_feather.html) does not have a way to explicitly set the memory map size. It does let you use a lower level `MemoryMappedFile` object though. But even within the lower level [`MemoryMappedFile` documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.MemoryMappedFile.html), I can't seem to find a way to specify the size of the memory map to be smaller than the file being loaded. How do I work with an Arrow IPC file that's larger than memory?

Comment: Can you please include some example code with your question? It should be possible to work with an Arrow IPC file larger than your system's memory but you have to avoid calling code that causes the entire file to be materialized.

Comment: I believe this is happening just after accessing the data frame returned by `pyarrow.feather.read_feather`. However, I'm not currently in front of the setup where this was running, so I will have to wait to confirm this.